# Replace characters that are enclosed with quotes using a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I replace characters with `preg_replace`, that are enclosed in quotes?

I need to replace all special characters, that are in `href=""` things. Example:

```
<a href="ööbik">ööbik</a> should become <a href="oobik">ööbik</a>
```

Comment: Had any luck with my solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace the "special chars", you need to use [iconv](http://php.net/iconv): `$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);`

As for getting the values in between the quotes, see the other answers. Use `preg_replace_callback` to execute the conversion above on the matches.

EDIT: spoon-feeding everything together:

```
<?php
$input = 'ööbik';
$expected = 'ööbik';

// Set the locale of your input here.
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');

// Convert using a callback.
$output = preg_replace_callback('/href="([^"]+)"/', function ($matches) {
    return iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $matches[0]);
}, $input);

echo "Input:    $input\n";
echo "Expected: $expected\n";
echo "Output:   $output\n";
```

This example assumes PHP 5.3. Use "create_function" or a named function if you are stuck on PHP 5.2 or below.

Comment: BTW, I wholeheartedly agree with not using regular expressions for parsing HTML. For instance, this code does not work for single-quoted href='' attributes. Use DOMDocument::loadHTML, for instance.

Comment: I just love it when new users come here to get a quick answer and then vamoose! Also, I love the word "vamoose".

Answer (score 0):

While the Stack Overflow question *[Finding quoted strings with escaped quotes in C# using a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148587)* may help you finding quoted text, I think the better solution is to do this by parsing an HTML string and work with its [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: I do agree that using regexp on HTML is generally a bad idea, but when you only need to fetch a very specific string from a HTML document, like a single attribute, a regexp is fine.

Comment: Agree, it depends on a specific case.