# Regex in C# - remove quotes and escaped quotes from a value after another value

Tags: c#, regex

I am using HighCharts and am generating script from C# and there's an unfortunate thing where they use inline functions for formatters and events. Unfortunately, I can't output JSON like that from any serializer I know of. In other words, they want something like this:

```
"labels":{"formatter": function() { return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0); }}
```

And with my serializers available to me, I can only get here:

```
"labels":{"formatter":"function() { return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0); }"}
```

These are used for click events as well as formatters, and I absolutely need them.

So I'm thinking regex, but it's been years and years and also I was never a regex wizard.

What kind of Regex replace can I use on the final serialized string to replace any quoted value that starts with function() with the unquoted version of itself? Also, the function itself may have " in it, in which case the quoted string might have \" in it, which would need to also be replaced back down to ".

I'm assuming I can use a variant of the first answer here:

[Finding quoted strings with escaped quotes in C# using a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148587/regex-quoted-string-with-escaped-quotes-in-c-sharp)

but I can't seem to make it happen. Please help me for the love of god.

I've put more sweat into this, and I've come up with

```
    serialized = Regex.Replace(serialized, @"""function\(\)[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*""", "function()$1");
```

However, my end result is always:

```
formatter:function()$1
```

This tells me I'm matching the proper stuff, but my capture isn't working right. Now I feel like I'm probably being an idiot with some C# specific regex situation.

Update: Yes, I was being an idiot. I didn't have a capture around what I really wanted.

```
   `enter code here` serialized = Regex.Replace(serialized, @"""function\(\)([^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*)""", "function()$1");
```

that gets my match, but in a case like this:

```
"formatter":"function() { alert(\"hi!\"); return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0); }"
```

it returns:

```
"formatter":function() { alert(\"hi!\"); return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0); }
```

and I need to get those nasty backslashes out of there. Now I think I'm truly stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    string serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(chartDefinition);
    serialized = Regex.Replace(serialized, @"""function\(\)([^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*)""", "function()$1").Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Regexp for match

```
"function\(\) (?<code>.*)"
```

Replace expression

```
function() ${code}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :** http://regexr.com?30jpf

What it does :

Finds double quotes JUST before a function declaration and immediately after it.

**Regex :**

```
(")(?=function()).+(?<=\})(")
```

**Replace groups 1 & 3 with nothing :**

```
3 capturing groups: 
   group 1: (")
   group 2: ()
   group 3: (")
```

Comment: Does this take escaped quotes into consideration?

Comment: @InsidiousForce What do you mean? `\"` WITHIN `"function() { return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0); }"`?

Comment: yeah they will be there sometimes, " will have been escaped as \" by the serializer.

Comment: @InsidiousForce Just checked it. No problem at all if there is an escaped quote within `"function() { return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0); }"`. Have a look : http://regexr.com?30jpi

Comment: @InsidiousForce Just make sure to replace group 1 and 3, just these. I'd write the exact code needed, but honestly it's been a while since I've played with C# and I'm not going to take my chances...

Comment: See my new update - I need to make sure that anything inside is unescaped, your code matches all of it but the result is same as mine, nothing unescaped. right?

Comment: @InsidiousForce Have you tried it out? (I'm a Mac user, so give one min to install Mono; and I'll let you know) - also, could you post a bigger sample (of what you want to convert, I mean) so that I can run my test against it?

Comment: @InsidiousForce Also, if the escaped quotes is your only issue, why don't you just replace `\"` with `"` in your final string?

Comment: that makes sense, and that is what I did. was trying to do it all in one regex, just got locked on that idea and got stuck. thanks for your help.