# Regex for ignoring consecutive quotation marks in string

Tags: c#, regex, sprache

I have built a parser in Sprache and C# for files using a format I don't control. Using it I can correctly convert:

```
a = "my string";
```

into

```
my string
```

The parser (for the quoted text only) currently looks like this:

```
public static readonly Parser<string> QuotedText =
    from open in Parse.Char('"').Token()
    from content in Parse.CharExcept('"').Many().Text().Token()
    from close in Parse.Char('"').Token()
    select content;
```

However the format I'm working with escapes quotation marks using "double doubles" quotes, e.g.:

```
a = "a ""string"".";
```

When attempting to parse this nothing is returned. It should return:

```
a ""string"".
```

Additionally

```
a = "";
```

should be parsed into a `string.Empty` or similar.

I've tried regexes unsuccessfully based on answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148587/finding-quoted-strings-with-escaped-quotes-in-c-sharp-using-a-regular-expression) doing things like `"(?:[^;])*"`, or:

```
public static readonly Parser<string> QuotedText =
    from content in Parse.Regex("""(?:[^;])*""").Token()
```

This doesn't work (i.e. no matches are returned in the above cases). I think my beginners regex skills are getting in the way. Does anybody have any hints?

EDIT: I was testing it here - http://regex101.com/r/eJ9aH1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this is the kind of regex you're looking for:

```
"(?:""|[^"])*"
```

See the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/dN9vD1).
 1. `"` matches an opening quote
 2. `(?:""|[^"])*` matches two quotes or any chars that are not a quote (including newlines), repeating
 3. `"` matches the closing quote.

But it's always going to boil down to whether your input is balanced. If not, you'll be getting false positives. And if you have a string such as `"string"", which should be matched?`"string""`,`""`, or nothing?... That's a tough decision, one that, fortunately, you don't have to make if you are sure of your input.

Comment: Thanks - I can fairly safely assume the files I get are balanced inputs as they go through a lint process before I get to them. I'll try this out in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can likely adapt your desired output from this pattern:

```
"(.+".+")"|(".+?")|("")
```

example:

http://regex101.com/r/lO1vZ4

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick although as @zx81 answered a bit earlier I've marked his as correct.

Comment: @will-hart, no worries - glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to ignore consecutive double quotes, try this:

```
("{2,})
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/vW0yS1)**

Comment: As can be seen in your demo, this doesn't still ignore `""`.

Comment: @AmalMurali I update my regex. Amal regex just select for you the matching patter, it does not ignore or replace or do anything for you. In order to modify the selected part you need to use a method to replace what is in between parenthesis by an empty string

Comment: As the title of the question says, the OP is trying to create a "*regex for ignoring consecutive quotation marks in string*". Your regex still matches consecutive double-quotes, which the OP *doesn't* want.

Comment: I am matching the double quotes so they can be replaced by empty string, isn't it easier ?

Comment: No, because in the process of matching consecutive double-quotes, you are also matching `"""`, `""""` etc.

Comment: I can fix this, but he/she didn't mention that only 2 consecutive double-quotes must be ignored @AmalMurali

Answer (score 0):

This regex `"("+)` might help you to match extra unwanted double quotes.

here is the [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fZ8tR7)