# Python : transform complex list-like string into list (without SyntaxError for mixing bytes and nonbytes literal)

Tags: python, string, list, numpy

I have this string : `u'''[ "A", """B""",'C' , " D"]'''`

I would like to get a list like : `["A","""B""",'C'," D"]` *edited as ""B"" was not valid indeed

Some use "" "" or ' ' to escape ' or " or both inside.

I tried various solutions from :
[Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

```
s= u'''[ "A", """B""",'C' , " D"]'''
```

1)

```
import numpy as np
List = np.array(s).tolist()
print(List)
print(type(List))
```

Result :

```
[ "A", """B""",'C' , " D"]
<class 'str'>
```

So not a list, then :

2)

```
import ast
List = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(List)
print(type(List))
```

Result

```
SyntaxError: cannot mix bytes and nonbytes literals
```

Any other idea how to do it ? (I m using Python 3.6)

I thought of regex or simple string replacements but when I think of all the cases where we escape replacing characters like ", ' in the list elements it gets complicated real fast

Comment: `""B""` is not valid

Comment: @bobrobbob Yeah and if it was valid like `u'''[ "A", "B",'C' , " D"]'''` you could just do `eval(s)`

Comment: can you provide some complicated examples?

Answer (score 2):

Using `ast.literal_eval(s)` works great as long as there are no unescaped quotes present. We can fix that using regex. Unfortunately, it's not that easy. However, I got a silver bullet for you.

First, let's identify all quoted substrings that have inner quotes of the same type:

```
(?<=[\[,])\s*(['\"])(?:(\1)|.)*?\1(?=\s*[,\]])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=[\[,])` front anchor using lookbehind: beginning of a list or previous list element: `[` or `,`
- `\s*` zero or more whitespace
- `(['\"])` opening quote in capture group
- `(?:(\1)|.)*?` lazy match any character, if same quote as in `$1` put it in `$2`
- `\1` closing quote using a back reference
- `(?=\s*[,\]])` rear anchor using lookahead: `,` or `]`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ZQV1oC/4)

Now, the real fun starts. Next, search substrings that have inner quotes of the same type for **unescaped** quotes.

To do so, I use the [Skip_what_to_avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29452781/8291949) approach with some advanced regex technique like an [unrolled loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148587/finding-quoted-strings-with-escaped-quotes-in-c-sharp-using-a-regular-expression).

```
^"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*"$|^'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'$|^\s*["'][^"'\\]*|["']\s*$|\\.|(["'])[^"'\\\n]*
```

The key idea here is to completely disregard the overall matches returned by the regex engine: `$0` is the trash bin. Instead, we only need to check capture group `$1`, which, when set, contains what we are looking for. Basically, all these uncaptured alternations match regular, properly escaped substrings enclosed in quotation marks. We only want the unescaped ones.

[**Demo2**](https://regex101.com/r/myCj1V/6)

I decided to reassemble the original string with the necessary `\` added to properly escape those unescaped quotes. There are certainly other ways.

Finally, putting all together the full sample code ([online demo](https://ideone.com/jDdZZi)):

```
import re
import ast

test = ("[ \"A\", \"\"B\"\",'C' , \" D\"]\n"
    "[ \"A\", \"'B'\",'C' , \" D\"]\n"
    "[ \"A\", ''B'','C' , \" D\"]\n"
    "[ \"A\", '\"B\"','C' , \" D\"]\n"
    "[ \"A\", '8 o'clock','C' , \" D\"]\n"
    "[ \"A\", \"Ol' 8 o'clock\",'C' , \" D\"]\n"
    "[\"Some Text\"]\n"
    "[\"Some more Text\"]\n"
    "[\"Even more text about \\\"this text\\\"\"]\n"
    "[\"Ol' 8 o'clock\"]\n"
    "['8 o'clock']\n"
    "[ '8 o'clock']\n"
    "['Ol' 8 o'clock']\n"
    "[\"\"B\"]\n"
    "[\"\\\"B\"]\n"
    "[\"\\\\\"B\"]\n"
    "[\"\\\\\\\"B\"]\n"
    "[\"\\\\\\\\\"B\"]")
result = u''
last_index = 0
regex1 = r"(?<=[\[,])\s*(['\"])(?:(\1)|.)*?\1(?=\s*[,\]])" #nested quotes of the same type
regex2 = r'''^"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*"$|^'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'$|^\s*["'][^"'\\]*|["']\s*$|\\.|(["'])[^"'\\\n]*''' # unescaped quotes in $1
matches = re.finditer(regex1, test, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    if match.groups()[1] is not None: #nested quotes of the same type present
        print(match.group())
        inner = re.finditer(regex2, match.group())
        for m in inner:            
            if m.groups()[0] is not None: # unescaped quotes in $1 present
                result += test[last_index:match.start() + m.start()] + '\\' + m.group()
                last_index = match.start()+m.end()
result += test[last_index:len(test)]
print(result)

for test_str in result.split("\n"):
    List = ast.literal_eval(test_str)
    print(List)
    print(type(List))
```

We have test string that contains several lists as a string literal with all sorts of special cases: different and same types of quotes, escaped quotes, escaped escape sequences, etc. The test string is cleansed using the outlined solution above, `split`, and then individually converted to a list using `literal_eval`.

This is probably one of the most advanced regex solutions I have crafted so far.