# Matching an arbitrary Python string with Python regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, regexp-replace

I'm working with a Python source code corpus. I would like the strings to be replaced with `STRING`. Python strings are annoying because they allow so many delimiters. Here is what I've tried and the issues I've run into.

- `r'"(\\"|[^"])*"'` and `r"'(\\'|[^'])*'"`

  This doesn't work because if a string contains the opposite delimiter.
- `r'(\'|"|\'\'\'|""")(?:\\\1|(?!\1))*\1'`

  This was my attempt at a catch all, but the lookahead doesn't work. I basically wanted `r'(\'|"|\'\'\'|""")(?:\\\1|[^\1])*\1'` if that were possible.
- Multiline strings mess stuff up. You can't use `[^"""]` because `"""` is not one character.
- Strings that contain the other delimiters like `"'"`.
- Strings that escape the delimiter like `'\''`.

These are the kinds of strings that need to be matched. The entire block is a string with the delimiters included.

- `` '/$\'"`' ``
- `'\\'`
- `'^__[\'\\"]([^\'\\"]*)[\'\\"]'`
- `"Couldn't do that"`

These are all valid strings, but you can probably see where it might be hard to match them. Essentially, I want this:

```
def hello_world():
    print("'blah' \"blah\"")
```

To become:

```
def hello_world():
    print( STRING )
```

For simplicity sake, let's say the entire Python file is inside of a string. Right now I am reading a file line by line, but I could treat it as one string if necessary. **It really doesn't matter how the file is read. If your solution requires a specific method, I will use that.**
I am not sure this problem can be solved entirely with regex. If you have a solution that involves other code, that would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: Why not process this at the AST level, rather than trying to regex the source?

Comment: I am also considering that approach, but I want to test this approach as well.

Comment: Why not join the four regexes for `"""`, `'''`, `"` and `'` with `|` between them?

Comment: I've tried that, but I am having trouble using a lookahead.

Comment: `r'(\'|"|\'\'\'|""")(?:\\\1|(?!\1))*\1'`

Comment: I mean `'|'.join([r'"(\\"|[^"])*"', r"'(\\'|[^'])*'"])` (but with the triplers as well).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. I will try it.

Comment: You're also missing raw strings (`r'...'`), f-strings (`f'...'`), and probably some others. I suspect f-strings in particular are unparseable with a regex because they can contain arbitrary Python expressions, including other string literals.

Comment: @Mike Can you show an example of a problematic f-string?

Comment: @HeapOverflow It looks like I was wrong; expressions in f-strings aren't allowed to contain the same quote character that was used to enclose the string, even escaped. That breaks every way I can think of to make arbitrarily deep f-strings. (I assume I was thinking of the C# equivalent, where `$"a string{"another string"}"` is allowed and requires no escaping.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a regex that matches quoted strings but allows escaping:

```
[rR]?(?:'([^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*)'|"([^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)")
```

[Demo](http://%20https://regex101.com/r/vGuO8r/1)

While this may capture the majority of strings I am pretty sure there are still some exceptions.

This is based on J. Friedl's [unrolling the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148587/finding-quoted-strings-with-escaped-quotes-in-c-sharp-using-a-regular-expression) technique:

Unrolling the Loop (using double quotes)

```
"                              # the start delimiter
 ([^\\"]*                      # anything but the end of the string or the escape char
         (?:\\.                #     the escape char preceding an escaped char (any char)
               [^\\"]*         #     anything but the end of the string or the escape char
                      )*)      #     repeat
                             " # the end delimiter
```